# How to uninstall/remove Developer Tools from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Our users should use Ctrl+Shift+J shortcut in web application.

We have tried Chrome switchers like '--disable-dev-tools' but it not works in our scenario.

Comment: Best suggestion? Use a different shortcut.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Disabling the developer tools is difficult but you can do it:

1. Open Chrome (Or Chromium).
2. Open the developer tools by pressing F12 and resize the developer tools panel by moving the splitter (Sounds strange, but trust me). You don't have to do this if you are sure that you have resized it before.
3. Close all Chrome windows.
4. On Windows 7 open the file `C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` in your favourite text editor. On Linux the file is located at `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`. On Windows XP it may be somewhere else. Don't know.
5. Search for `devtools`. You will find a section which looks like this:

   `"devtools": { "split_location": 256 }`

   (That's why I told you to change the panel size in step 2. When you don't do this then this section does not exist and you have to create it manually somewhere.)
6. Change this section so it looks like this:

   `"devtools": { "disabled": true, "split_location": 256 }`
7. Save the file.
8. Start Chromium. Press F12. Nothing happens. Press Ctrl+Shift+J. Nothing happens. Right-click and try to select the Inspector. Doesn't work.
9. Be happy.

Comment: It's for an unrelated purpose but it works. Also, there's `--debug-devtools-frontend=0` if you're bundling Chrome. It will open `Webpage not found`

Comment: 2018 Linux Opera/Chromium, ` "disabled": true` did nothing. On reboot, it was gone. Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.64

Answer (score 4):

```
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
   return false;
}
document.onkeydown = function (e) { 
    if (window.event.keyCode == 123 ||  e.button==2)    
    return false;
}
```

Use this code to disable rightclick & F12 on ur page, but there is no way to stop a user from opening Dev Tools Menu > Tools > Developer tools

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Disabling the whole of right-click really only masks the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the policy **DeveloperToolsAvailability** - see https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DeveloperToolsAvailability

Answer (score -1):

```
disable-dev-tools
```

Working great for me, Are you sure you're not writing something wrong, please recheck.

See: http://www.chromeplugins.org/tips-tricks/chrome-command-line-switches/

This website is closed. :(((

Comment: Scenario: 1. Start Chrome (v10.0.648.205) with '--disable-dev-tools' 2. Press Ctrl+Shift+J shortcut 3. Chrome opens disabled Dev tools console

Comment: @Alexander Byndyu: i will test this asap.

Comment: @Alexander Byndyu: you're correct it's no working on the version you provided, i am doing an extra research to see what's the problem and will back to you asap.

Comment: user1099531 it seems not possible at the moment as @loislo said.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Not true. See my answer below.

Comment: Not true.  Your answer is above! ;)