# Prevent Google Chrome Log XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Is it possible to `prevent` Google Chrome from logging `XMLHttpRequests`?

I don't mean to `disable` the function on Console, but my code is `not` letting Google Chrome show the `URL` to the user.

---

[Update] I am offering a bounty to find out how to suppress messages like

```
XHR Loaded (controllers.js - 200 OK - 12.728999950923026ms - 103.516KB)
```

Comment: You could disable Chrome Dev Tools entirely: [How to uninstall/remove Developer Tools from Google Chrome?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692006/how-to-uninstall-remove-developer-tools-from-google-chrome

Comment: I don't think your question is valid. Browsers are meant to process and show requests, otherwise world would be a too dangerous and mysterious place

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The logging entry in chrome's console is a behavior of chrome when any `HTTP request` is handled, not a problem with jQuery or ajax(XMLHttpRequest), even an `<img>` or `<link>` tag could cause this issue.

**[Give This a try though](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/console)**

Answer (score 10):

You can turn this off in the Developer Console settings. Click the three dots in the upper right hand corner of the tools, go to settings and disable `Log XHR requests`

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Open Developer console. Open settings from kebab menu. Under Console, there is an option to disable logging XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 2):

Use `console.clear()` in your error handling callbacks/rejections.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, because this is a setting which the end user has to set in the browser. What you can do is make a XMLHttpRequest to a PHP script which serves your desired content, instead of making the call directly. This way the end user will see only the URL to the PHP script in the console.