# Developer tools getting disabled

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I am on Version 45.0.2454.101 m and for some reason dev tools option is getting disabled.

---

> ***I reinstalled chrome 3 times, no luck.***

---

I tried to delete the registry file based on this answer
[Google chrome develop tools disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726308/google-chrome-develop-tools-disabled)

I do not see chromium under policy folder :(.

I searched the user data --> Default --> Preferences folder to see if I can delete the devtools reference, nothing helped :(

**Update:
Based on lossleader's comment I checked chrome://policy and I see devtools is disabled, how should i enable or set this to false**

[image]

Please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

***UPDATE : 10/13/2015
My preference file as of today, still   dev console is disabled:***

[image]

10/16/2015 I do not see anything under group policy object too

[image]

Comment: someone pleaseeeeeeee help me solve this nightmare, my inspect element is getting disabled for no reason :(

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of this before.  Do `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I` or `F12` work?

Comment: nope, none of the shortcuts work. I am not able to access the developer tools from the settings menu too :(

Comment: Have you tried looking to see if it's disabled per the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692006/how-to-uninstall-remove-developer-tools-from-google-chrome)?

Comment: @ajp15243 I cannot do the step 2 and also I do not see anything than what I have updated in my question when I search for devtools

Comment: You confirmed that `"disabled"` doesn't appear within the `"devtools"` entry? Perhaps explicitly set `"disabled": false` in the entry?

Comment: Search could not find disabled keyword in the entire file :(

Comment: I submitted this issue to google, but I am sure I would be long dead before someone from google looks into it.

Comment: Have some faith in the process. Plenty of bugs have been solved that way.    Did you try putting `"disabled": false` into the `"devtools"` entry?  Maybe also see if [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-projects) (open-source project on which Google Chrome is based) also has it disabled or not.  If it is, you could submit a bug to the Chromium project.

Comment: I added "disabled": false and saved the preference file, but when I close and reopen chrome the preference file is being overwritten by some other process and the "disabled": false is no more seen in the preference file

Comment: The preferences being overwritten when Chrome starts up sounds suspicious. I'm curious to know if: 1) You use Chrome Sign-in, 2) You use any Chrome extensions, 3) Chromium has the same problem, 4) Deleting your `AppData\Roaming\Google` folder helps, and 5) You have any suspicious processes or if AV detects any viruses/malware.

Comment: 1) Yes, I sign in to my gmail as soon as I reinstall chrome,not sure if this is what you mean by sign-in  2) I have deleted and disabled all extensions under the same suspesion 3) my pc has anti virus, defender and also used cc cleaner nothing suspicious going on

Comment: No, not Gmail.  [Chrome has it's own sign-in](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en).  It does use your Google account, which you also use for Gmail and other Google services (they consolidated accounts for their products a little while back).

Comment: Nope I am not using any sign in then

Comment: Did you go to chrome://policy and check which policies are set to non default values and what DeveloperToolsDisabled is set to?

Comment: @lossleader I see that developerToolsDisabled = True, how do I set it to false?

Comment: @rao maybe I found a way to do this, since if you delete this policy, then it won't be set. Check my edit and let me know!

Comment: I'd look at the extensions and update urls in the `ExtensionInstallForcelist` value to figure out what this overall policy is and where it may be from. I also think the chrome://policy url would have a source column if you were using the latest dev-channel chrome.

Comment: @lossleder I am at loss on how to fix this, I am not seeing a source column

Comment: @rao I think you'll only see the source column if you install the dev version of Chrome with unreleased features, per lossleader's comment. You likely just have the stable released version, as that's the default.

Comment: @rao I asked you how my answer worked, you didn't answer. I had some other ideas too, but no I forgot them, since days have passed. It's a pity for your bounty!

Comment: Did you check you Chrome's Shortcut icon ? Check its properties and see that its target doesn't has this string written: **chrome --disable-dev-tools** at the end

Comment: @gsamaras very sorry there is too much going on here I missed it :(. Unfortunately I do not see google folder under policies at all whatsoever I do. I had someone look at it and he added a registry key still no luck. Again I am very sorry I never ignored but got caught up.

Comment: @DeepakYadav I have full control and do not see any kind of string. thanks though :)

Comment: I have the exact same situation.  my chrome has dev tools disabled after a   machine reboot.

Comment: @silverArc Same with me you do not have to reboot just log off and log back in, your dev tools would be gone. I dont see incognito, extensions also.

Comment: I think the disabled property should simply be omitted as its default is false. If it shows up anyway then a system policy has priority over your preferences. But really, if you aren't using a corporate machine, then I would look for the source of all 3 strange policies, which the dev line's chrome://policy may give more data about: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: @lossleader the source says "Platform"

Comment: It looks like machine+platform should mean machine level GPO was instaled, but it also seems like a few things may get called this wrongly, i.e. a policy directory in your user profile directory, did you try a fresh profile? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en

Comment: I managed to solve it for Mac OS X Apple users:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491017/chrome-developer-tools-disabled-on-mac/69476504#69476504

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1 - **Close** Chrome
2 - **Open the file:**

```
C:\users\[your users account]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
```

3 - **SEARCH FOR:**

```
"devtools": {
something...
"disabled": true,
something...
},
```

4 - **CHANGE TO:**

```
"devtools": {
something...
"disabled": false,
something...
},
```

5 - **Restart** Chrome.

---

**DISABLED:**
[image]

**ENABLED:**
[image]

---

**NOTES**
**1 -**  If you cannot find `"disabled": true,` just add the value `"disabled": false,`  under `devtools`.
**2 -** You may want to copy the contents of the file to  http://jsonlint.com/ in order to read properly.
**3 -** **Backup** the Original file (just in case)
**4 -** I've tested `enabling` and `disabling` **devtools** and it works as expected.
**5 -** If the problem persists, you may want to **disable your extensions** in order to ensure they aren't messing with your preferences. The same applies to antivirus.

---

**UPDATE**

> *notepad ++ complaints saying the source file has been modified by
> another program*

This is normal, other values may have changed in the file, which is expected. However, the values you have added will not change.

Comment: I do not see anything inside the "devtools"{ } as mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @rao I've the file opened right now and it contains `devtools`,  please read the TIPS of my answer.

Comment: Just add `"disabled": false, ` right after `"devtools": {`

Comment: I can assure it works and this is the right solution :)

Comment: As previously mentioned the preferences file is being modified by some other program every time I open chrome :(. I save it open chrome and notepad ++ complaints saying the source file has been modified by another program. I load the modified file and the disabled:false is gone

Comment: Just click the **X** button  when you restart chrome. it won't bug you again.

Comment: You're complicating something easy, while talking with you I've already enabled and disable it several times.

Comment: Pedro Chrome does not complaint anything, notepad++ is complaining that the file is being modified when I save the preferences file and restart chrome. When chrome restarts some process is overwriting the chrome preferences file. I totally understand what you are asking me to do but unfortunately I am unable to apply the fix provided by you.

Comment: Close chrome first, edit the file , restart chrome. I can assure you it works.

Comment: I totally appreciate your efforts to help me out and want to award the bounty for the efforts, but even after setting  disabled:false in preferences the dev console wont show up :(

Comment: I still have not solved this, but for the efforts you put in I want to assign the bounty to you :). Thanks again for trying to help me

Comment: I'm sorry to ear that.  I honestly don't know how to help you further. You may want to report the problem to google https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en , GL !

Comment: I already did :/ hoping some day debugging around I will find an answer to this mystery

Answer (score 5):

Try deleting this folder:

```
[user drive]\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\Google
```

which I got from a Superuser [question](https://superuser.com/questions/696770/chrome-developer-tools-disabled).

---

Or, do:

Press the Windows key + R, type regedit.exe and press Enter 
HKEY_USERS\ -> S-1-5-21-1177238915-1897051121-839522115-1003\ -> Software\ -> Microsoft\ -> Windows\ -> CurrentVersion\ -> Group Policy Objects\ -> {91DD4E7D-FE0F-4B62-A092-91DC1486888E}User\ -> Software\ -> Policies\ -> Google\ -> Chrome

Delete the ones in RED. Click on "Google" and click on "Edit" and select "Delete".
Click on "File" and then "Exit".

Did it work?

Comment: I updated my question with what I see under group policy objects, thanks for the help :)

Comment: As long as you fixed the issue, I am happy @rao!

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a Windows box, but you didn't say if it's a personal or work computer.

Looking at the policy in chrome://policy, you will notice that the policy is being set at the "Machine" level.

Read google's documentation [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202):

---

**Machine Policies** are applied through Group Policy Objects (GPO) on Windows..

..(machine policies) are **pushed to the user using Windows Group Policy Objects**  (GPO), Managed Preferences on Mac, or another **out-of-band management system** for Windows/Mac/Linux..

---

In other words, it's likely that your workplace has set up a group policy object and is forcing these 3 settings onto your machine. Group Policy Objects generally can't be disabled and often can't even be seen by a non-administrator. Note that when I say "administrator" I'm talking about a domain admin, not a local-machine admin.

The purpose of group policy ("Managed Preferences" on the Mac) is to force certain settings onto a large group of machines. Common examples include password policies, ability to install plug-ins, etc.

It looks like someone in your organization thinks that disabling Chrome's developer tools and incognito mode are good for security. This is kind of a dumb idea, but that's not relevant to the discussion.

**EDIT:** "that would be highly unlikely but I will look"

You have more confidence in your IT department than I do. :)

Someone probably read [this NSA "briefing"](https://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/app/deploying_and_securing_google_chrome_in_a_windows_enterprise.pdf) and thought it was a good idea.

Comment: that would be highly unlikely but I will look into this and get back

Comment: I sat with an admin and he assured there are no policies preventing devconsole

Answer (score 2):

If you are logged into Google under a managed account that has the preference off, you'll have to log out to get around it. Other than that the administrator of your account has to change the setting for you to be able to use Dev Tools in Chrome.

Comment: my company admin has clearly stated there are no policies around chrome that restricts dev tools

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was changing this value:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\DeveloperToolsDisabled
```

to 0

Unfortunately, after a logon or some time (I'm no domain admin) the setting is set to 1 again. Thinking about starting Chrome via a batch file and applying the value to the registry key, like this

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /v DeveloperToolsDisabled /t REG_DWORD /f /d 0
```

Complete commandline (with UAC):

```
powershell Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C","'reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /v DeveloperToolsDisabled /t REG_DWORD /f /d 0'" -Verb runAs
```

Complete batch file:

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v "DeveloperToolsDisabled" | Find "0x0"

If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto start_chrome

powershell Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C","'reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /v DeveloperToolsDisabled /t REG_DWORD /f /d 0'" -Verb runAs

:start_chrome
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of **Microsoft Edge**, I changed the **DeveloperToolsAvailability** setting value from:

**2** (*Don't allow using developer Tools*)
to
**1** (*Allow using the developer tools*)

Set the Registry Key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\DeveloperToolsAvailability
```

And check afterwards:

**edge://policy**

But since this is work laptop, you at mercy of site admins, when they run group policies. But this worked for me, on laptop where setting is controlled by group policy

Reference: ([DeveloperToolsAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/Microsoft-edge-policies#developertoolsavailability))

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below or refer to these 4 screenshots to enable developer tools.
You will need to be familiar with the Windows registry editor.

1. Run regedit :Windows key +r then type regedit or search for it
2. Browse registy to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`
3. Double click on DeveloperToolsDisbaled
4. Change the value from 1 to 0
5. Issue should be resolved

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome:
[image: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]

DeveloperToolsDisabled:
[image: DeveloperToolsDisabled]

Change Value to 0:
[image: Change Value to 0]

Developer Tools should now be enabled:
[image: Developer Tools should now be enabled]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how helpful this will be, but are there any other unknown processes running in task manager on your computer. This sounds less like a bug and more like some malware may be forcefully editing any chrome installation. It could also be that when you re-install chrome and sign in some kind of chrome add-on is being loaded which is causing problems.

Comment: tried everything ran malware bytes, cc cleaner, windows defender no malware or virus