# Chrome Developer Tools disabled on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know questions on how to enable Chrome developer tools have been answered in the past but they are for Windows. I am on a Mac and the Developer Tools in grayed out and so is inspect element. How do I re-enable them on my mac?

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Not seen this before. I recommend simply resetting your Chrome in chrome://settings/

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1 - Reset Chrome's Flags

On `chrome://flags` press the `Reset All` button.

### Solution 2 - Modify Chrome's Policies

On `chrome://policy` we can see Chrome's current policies.

If [DeveloperToolsDisabled](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=DeveloperToolsDisabled) is set to `true`, quit Chrome and open Terminal, set:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome DeveloperToolsDisabled -bool false
```

If [DeveloperToolsAvailability](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=DeveloperToolsAvailability) is set to `2`, quit Chrome and open Terminal, set:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome DeveloperToolsAvailability -int 0
```

*Note: if you get an error message saying your browser is managed, then it means you are a part of an organization, and only your organization's IT person can help you.*